# Do not have permission to open the created .mdf file using my application

Tags: .net

in Windows 7 log in as normal user then i am able to create .mdf file using my application, but not able to open the same file. It says i don't have permissions to open contact administrator. Let me know the reason.

Answer (score 0):

you should put the file in a folder with permission . usually its data folder inside the sql installation dir ( or one of its childs) ...

put the file there and them youll be able to open the file

Comment: tried your answer but same issue. what we are doing in the application is copying template .mdf file using File.Copy after copying the file the permissions (.\users) are intact, But after executing SqlConnection.Open() its removing the permissions to the Project file.